# Getting exception while getting the ethBalance

Tags: web3j

web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService());

```
         EthGetBalance ethGetBalance = web3.ethGetBalance("0xb34a5b6a39bceafeb8e23c2cc526889d85bf664e", DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
         BigInteger balance = ethGetBalance.getBalance();
         System.out.println("balance - "+balance);
```

---

java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8545
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:225)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:211)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService.performIO(HttpService.java:106)
    at org.web3j.protocol.Service.send(Service.java:30)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.Request.send(Request.java:68)
    at com.mobiloitte.coinbase.TestEthreum.createConnection(TestEthreum.java:56)
    at com.mobiloitte.coinbase.TestEthreum.main(TestEthreum.java:74)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:124)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:223)
    ... 25 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run node (geth for example) on your localhost and tell it to open rpc port

`geth  --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,debug" --rpccorsdomain "*"`

Be carefull, using --rpccorsdomain "*" is a security issue

Comment: I am running the node i.e GETH @alexey

Comment: @aman-vyas answer was edited

Comment: Thank you @Alexey It worked for me and It will be great help what actually you mean by security issue can you provide any reference for it.. Thanks in advance

Comment: @aman-vyas --rpccorsdomain "*" tells geth to accept connections from anywhere. Here is described this flag https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8854/6041. Here is described what can happen https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/648/6041